# Set string as int constant using Expression class

Tags: c#, dynamic, expression-trees

I'm dynamically creating an expression tree using values provided in an XML file (i.e. I read strings). The value and the type of the member are read from this file. I'm trying to create a `ConstantExpression` of an integer:

```
XElement expression = GetMyCurrentMember();
//<member type="System.Int32">5</member>

return Expression.Constant(expression.Value, Type.GetType(expression.Attribute("type").Value, false, true));
```

In the `return` statement I'm getting the error `Argument types do not match` which, upon inspection, seams about right since I'm passing a `string` and saying it's an `int`. A simple cast would (probably) solve the problem but that means that I'm loosing the dynamic of the whole system. Instead of `int` I could have `double` or `char` or even a custom type and I don't really want to create a different call or method for every type. Is there a method to "force" the automatic conversion of the input value to the requested type?

Comment: If you "own" the XML format, you might consider using XAML instead of plain XML.  That way you get strongly-typed values automatically.

Comment: @MikeStrobel unfortunatelly that's not an option. The expressions are going into a legacy file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for a wide variety of types, a simple [`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130977%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will do the trick:

```
XElement expression = GetMyCurrentMember();
//<member type="System.Int32">5</member>
var formatProv = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
var type = Type.GetType(expression.Attribute("type").Value, false, true);
var value = Convert.ChangeType(expression.Value, type, formatProv);
return Expression.Constant(value, type);
```

Please note that by providing a format provider you can explicitly specify the culture you want to use in the conversion.

Answer (score 3):

You could "convert" the value, but you need to decide what to do if the conversion fails:

```
string value = expression.Value;
Type type = Type.GetType(expression.Attribute("type").Value, false, true);

return Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(value, type), type);
```